# .net TypeConverters and domain usage

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In general, is there any reason not to use a TypeConverter for conversion chores involving custom types that have nothing to do with UI?

Im thinking about cases more complex than implict & explicit conversions.

Any links to design guidelines & samples for doing so?

Cheers,
Berryl

## UPDATE

Here is the motivation for the conversion, a Party - PartyRelationship pattern where a Party can have One or many  PartyNames. When the Party is a Person, the One required name is a PersonName.

The PersonName has attributes that are different from a PartyName and is a ValueObject. It is used for ui / formatting type tasks whereas the PartyName is an Entity and is persisted to the database.

So conversions are needed:
- Load from DB for presentation:    (PartyName --> PersonName)
- Add new contact to DB:            (PersonName --> PartyName)

[image]

Comment: A solution can only really be evaluated in context. Do you have examples of the the cases in which you are considering using type converters?

Comment: You are so right I had to upvote your comment also. See ammended post

Comment: @Bryan Watts. Am using explicit conversion operators now but leaning towards a TypeConverter to be more explicit and have support for UI culture. Problem is that I really don't know how to use TypeConverters well at all. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the data model of the problem you are solving. You mentioned that you are considering using type conversion for implementing some tasks around that data; can you give an overview of those tasks so we can determine how/if type conversion applies?

Comment: @Bryan Watts. Names are persisted as PartyName and presented as PersonName. So loading and saving to the db requires a type conversion.

Comment: So you have a persistent object with a property whose persistent form is `PartyName`. However, when you display this persistent object, you want to use a non-persistent form of the property for display. It sounds to me like you are using type conversion as a way of ironing out a wrinkle that is the result of binding the persistent object directly to a view. Does that sounds like your situation?

Comment: the wrinkle is it is more useful to persist generic PartyName which may apply to both People and Organizations in different contexts, including culture. The UI cannot ignore these differences tho, and needs dedicated objects like the PersonName.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [good link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy580hbd.aspx) that explains the difference between a `TypeConverter` and implementing `IConvertible`. But, basically, `TypeConverter` is built for, and most useful for, doing type conversions at design time. For example, it's how XAML converts types to XML and back.

`IConvertible` is generally more flexible, faster (it doesn't use reflection), and easier to implement than a `TypeConverter`. Unless you need the extra features that `TypeConverter` gives you (like the list of standard values), I would recommend you go with the interface option and use the `Convert` static methods.

Comment: isn't IConvertable only to go to .Net types tho? I am only dealing with custom types in this scenario.